# Eclipse Desktop Application

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I have developed  java Desktop application in eclipse, how to run(use) it in other system that is not having eclipse.
I want to install  application that i have developed in other systems not having eclipse.

Comment: you can explore your project to .jar file and execute from command line from any system you want.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu run Java Application you just need Java JRE and yourapp.jar.
You can do this as here:
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm
or just by build project correctly.

Comment: Thank u so much:-)

Answer (score 1):

use maven to package your app:
[how to create a maven project](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_eclispe_ide.htm)

the package phase in maven creates a yourApp.jar which can be executed by the jvm. (if installed on the system)

commandline:

> java -jar myApp.jar